# butterknife 8.5.1 error in Fragment

Tags: android

I use butterknife 8.5.1 in my fragment & the app make error :java.lang.IllegalStateException: Bindings already cleared.
below is part of my code:

file name:BaseFragment:
....

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (mView == null && context != null) {
        mView = inflater.inflate(getLayoutId(), container, false);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        }
        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, mView);
        initParams();
    } else if (mView != null) {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) mView.getParent();
        if (parent != null) {
            parent.removeView(mView);
        }
    }
    return mView;
}
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
        unbinder.unbind();


}
```

...
anyone ever met such problem and help? thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your line doesn't execute:

```
unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, mView);
```

Probably because your code not fulfit condition:

```
if (mView == null && context != null)
```

Bind it outside the condition like this:

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, mView);
    if (mView == null && context != null) {
        mView = inflater.inflate(getLayoutId(), container, false);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        }
        initParams();
    } else if (mView != null) {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) mView.getParent();
        if (parent != null) {
            parent.removeView(mView);
        }
    }
    return mView;
}
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
        unbinder.unbind();


}
```

Or you can check somehow if ButterKnife is binded.

Comment: I made mistake ,my code has been corrected to ensure this"unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, mView);" is running on the correct line ! it works ,thank u!@Mij

Answer (score 0):

Proper way to use `ButterKnife` in `fragment`:

```
private Unbinder unbinder;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main, container, false);

    unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    unbinder.unbind();
}
```